# Java 8 multilevel grouping and reducing

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a scenario where I have a list of objects of a type and I need to create a list of another objects of another type from it.

Below is the code: I have a list of Employees and need to create list of EmployeeInfo from the first list. Note that Employee has an account attribute, and the EmployeeInfo has a list of accounts. In this case, the same employee can have multiple accounts, so in the resulting employeeinfo list, each info object will have a list of accounts. Here is how i have done it:

```
public class Employee {

private final int dept;

private final String name;

private final String city;

private final String account;

public Employee(int dept, String name, String city, String account) {
    this.dept = dept;
    this.name = name;
    this.city = city;
    this.account = account;
}

public int getDept() {
    return dept;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public String getAccount() {
    return account;
}
```

}

```
public class EmployeeInfo {

private final String name;

private final List<String> accounts;

public EmployeeInfo(String name, List<String> accounts) {
    this.name = name;
    this.accounts = accounts;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public List<String> getAccounts() {
    return accounts;
}

public EmployeeInfo addToList(EmployeeInfo employeeInfo) {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.addAll(this.getAccounts());
    l.addAll(employeeInfo.getAccounts());
    return new EmployeeInfo(employeeInfo.name, l);
}
```

}

Test class:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    //tradeId, secPool, datasetid, restricValue
    employees.add(new Employee(1, "Mary", "Boston", "A1"));
    employees.add(new Employee(1, "Mary", "Boston", "A2"));
    employees.add(new Employee(1, "Alex", "NYC", ""));
    employees.add(new Employee(2, "Peter", "DC", ""));
    employees.add(new Employee(1, "Sophia", "DC", "A4"));

    TestEmployeeGrouping testEmployeeGrouping = new TestEmployeeGrouping();

    Map<Integer, List<EmployeeInfo>> result = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Map<String, List<Employee>>> map =  employees.stream().collect(groupingBy(Employee::getDept, groupingBy(testEmployeeGrouping::createKey)));
    map.forEach((integer, stringListMap) -> {
        List<EmployeeInfo> employeeInfos = createInfo(stringListMap);
        result.put(integer, employeeInfos);
    });


}

private static List<EmployeeInfo> createInfo(Map<String,List<Employee>> stringListMap) {
    List<EmployeeInfo> employeeInfos = new ArrayList<>();
    stringListMap.forEach((s, employees) -> {
        List<String> accounts = employees.stream().map(Employee::getAccount).collect(Collectors.toList());
        employeeInfos.add(new EmployeeInfo(employees.get(0).getName(), accounts));
    });
    return employeeInfos;
}


private String createKey(Employee employee) {
    return employee.getDept() + employee.getName();
}
```

While the above piece works fine, finally giving me a list of employeeinfo, grouped by dept, each with its list of accounts, I wanted to do it in amore funcitonal way like:

```
employees.stream().collect(groupingBy(Employee::getDept, groupingBy(testEmployeeGrouping::createKey, reducing(EmployeeInfo::addToList))));
```

The above line throws error: Incompatible types: T is not convertible to Employee. Can someone please help me figure out how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: you want to groupby on dept or name? or on both? same employee can have different departments right?

Comment: The result should be employee info, grouped by dept,  with each info having its account list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there any reason you made the `name` in `EmployeeInfo` final? if you can change that this solution will work

add these two methods to EmployeeInfo

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void AddAccount(String account) {
    this.accounts.add(account);
}
```

and then you can do this

```
Collector<Employee, EmployeeInfo, EmployeeInfo> empToInfo = Collector.of(
     () -> new EmployeeInfo("", new ArrayList<String>()),
            (info, e) -> { 
                info.AddAccount(e.getAccount());
                info.setName(e.getName());
                },
     (p1,p2) -> p1.addToList(p2));

Collector<Employee, ?, Collection<EmployeeInfo>> byName = collectingAndThen(groupingBy(Employee::getName, empToInfo), 
                  (Map<String, EmployeeInfo> finisher) -> {return finisher.values();});

Map<Integer, Collection<EmployeeInfo>> r2 = employees.stream().collect(groupingBy(Employee::getDept, byName));
```

if you want to keep The EmployeeInfo immutable, you can use reduction instead of collection and it will be like this

```
Map<Integer, Collection<EmployeeInfo>> result2 = employees.stream().collect(groupingBy(Employee::getDept,
             collectingAndThen(groupingBy(Employee::getName, reducing(new EmployeeInfo("", new ArrayList<String>()), 
                                                                      empl3 -> new EmployeeInfo(empl3.getName(),Arrays.asList(empl3.getAccount())), 
                                                                      (inf1, inf2) -> inf1.addToList(inf2))), 
                                finisher -> finisher.values())));
```

Comment: This one works too, I modified a bit the inner lambda part:                                                  `Map<Integer, Collection<EmployeeInfo>> result3 = employees.stream().collect(groupingBy(Employee::getDept,
                collectingAndThen(groupingBy(Employee::getName, reducing(new EmployeeInfo("", new ArrayList<String>()),
                        employee -> new EmployeeInfo(employee.getName(),Arrays.asList(employee.getAccount())),
                        EmployeeInfo::addToList)),
                        finisher -> finisher.values())));`

Answer (score 3):

This seems a bit complicated, but nothing is impossible

> First do the group by on dept and name into map key as dept and values as List
>
> second you need to do inner groupBy by employee `name`
>
> Then get the values from inner map and convert into employee info with list of accounts

```
  Map<Integer, List<EmployeeInfo>> empInfo = employees.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDept)).entrySet()
                         .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, value->value.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getName)).values()
                                 .stream().map(emp->new EmployeeInfo(emp.stream().findFirst().get().getName(), emp.stream().map(Employee::getAccount).collect(Collectors.toList())))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

**Output**

```
{1=[EmployeeInfo [name=Alex, accounts=[]], EmployeeInfo [name=Sophia, accounts=[A4]], EmployeeInfo [name=Mary, accounts=[A1, A2]]], 
 2=[EmployeeInfo [name=Peter, accounts=[]]]}
```

Comment: The result should be a map of dept, and its associated list of employee info(with its group of accounts),                                                                                                       1: Mary [A1, A2]
1: Alex []
2: Peter []
2: Sophia [A4]

Comment: In this case you have to do group by dept and name, try my solution produces this output @user1318369

Comment: I would need a map pf employee infos grouped by dept in the output, not just the list of employee info.

Comment: check it is this what you looking for @user1318369

Comment: and i will suggest do group by on dept+name, because dept `1` has multiple employees like `Mary`,`Alex`,`Sophia` @user1318369

Comment: Your solution has Map<String, EmployeeInfo>, but I need Map<String, List<EmployeeInfo>(as employess for a speciic dept should be in one list, below is the output of the map):                                                                                         1: [EmployeeInfo{name='Mary', accounts=[A1, A2]}, EmployeeInfo{name='Alex', accounts=[]}]
2: [EmployeeInfo{name='Peter', accounts=[]}, EmployeeInfo{name='Sophia', accounts=[A4]}]

Comment: A *bit* complicated is a *bit* of an understatement. IMO, what the OP had before was perfectly fine.

Comment: sorry i did not get this `A bit complicated is a bit of an understatement. IMO` you want me to add more explanation? yes whatever he had is perfectly fine, but he want to do it with complete streams @user991710

Comment: No, it was more of a tongue-in-cheek comment aimed at OP. I don't think he or anyone else will know what exactly is happening in that code (without looking at it for another 10 minutes) after a few days. :)